# My Button is not showing up in C# (Visual Studio Code)

Tags: c#, forms, button

I am trying to add a clickable button on a Form but is not showing up. I am working on Visual Studio Code and I am using the Designers code.

I have tried changing its attributes, size and position but nothing happens, what may be wrong?

```
    this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 620);
    this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    this.Text = "FORMULARIO";
    this.Controls.Add(label1);
    this.Controls.Add(txtbx1);
    this.Controls.Add(label2);
    this.Controls.Add(txtbx2);
    this.Controls.Add(label3);
    this.Controls.Add(txtbx3);
    this.Controls.Add(label4);
    this.Controls.Add(txtbx4);
    this.Controls.Add(btn);
    
    
    btn = new Button();
    btn.Text = "Submit";
    btn.Location = new Point(400, 100);
    btn.Size = new Size(100, 100);
    btn.BackColor = Color.Gray;
    btn.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
    btn.Font = new Font("Verdana", 16);
    btn.Click += new EventHandler(Button_Click);

}
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Thank You! ");
    this.Close();
}
private System.Windows.Forms.Button add;

#endregion
```

}

Comment: I thought that Visual Studio Code didn't support the Winforms designer. Sure you can write the code, but you can't see the form without running the app. Why are you using VS Code over regular Visual Studio?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Code since my Lap is too slow to run VS properly, instead VS Code is running smoothly. I have declared the button at the top of the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.Controls.Add(btn);


btn = new Button();
```

You are adding btn to Controls collection first. (Whereever you are initializing your btn variable). And then you create new Button(). Try to set up your button before adding to collection.

Comment: I did it, but again I am not seeing it.

Comment: can you also change btn.Location = new Point(400, 100) to btn.Location = new Point(0, 0) to test?